# LibGDX Scene2D and updating labels inside a table

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I have a ([Scene2d](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui)) Table containing a Label, both added to a Stage, and I'm properly calling `stage.act(float)` and `stage.draw()`. However, if I modify the text of the Label (using `setText()`) to be wider than the Table, the Table doesn't automatically widen, which I can tell because it's being rendered with a background. This is surprising to me since the `setText(CharSequence)` method calls [invalidateHierarchy()](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/db805953849780161df7c1fb96f81248c19cff44/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Label.java#L103), which I'd assume would be sufficient. I *suspect* if I were to then call `pack()` on the Table instance it would be sized correctly, but that seems like a code smell to me. (Calling `pack()` on the Label itself appears to do nothing.)

Should I be calling `pack()` on the Table anyway? Or should I be recursing up the `parent` hierarchy of the Label calling `pack()` as I go? Or is there some other sane way of handling this...

Thanks!

Comment: Post your code  :)

Comment: When adding label to table, do you use `expand` or `fill`?